# Match numbers that are not following an alphabet and place them in a capturing group (globally)

Tags: javascript, regex

For example, if I have text like this:

```
"hello800 more text 1234 and 567"
```

It should match `1234` and `567`, and not `800` (since it is following `hello`'s `o`, which is not a number).

It is similar to what programming languages do, for example, in JavaScript, `abc123` is a variable, while `50` alone, not following text, is treated as a number.

Please do have in mind that I want to negate only characters from the set `[A-Za-z]` and not others. For example, `+33` and `-33` should still return `33`.

My first trial was to match a NOT set:

```
[^A-Za-z]([0-9]+)
```

That didn't work at all.

My second trial was to reverse the string and to use a negative lookahead:

```
/([0-9]+)(?![A-Za-z])/g
```

It works only if there is 1 digit. `1a` does not match the `1` (and that's good), but `123a` matches the `12` (and that's bad).

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_match.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try the following regex

```
\b\d+\b
```

you can check the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/4UZ5Kl/1) here

additionally if you want to match +33 also you can try the regex

```
\b[+-]*\d+\b
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/4UZ5Kl/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this `\b(\d+?)\b`

- `\b` Checks for word boundaries (spaces, endlines, etc..)
- `\d` Checks for numbers

[Demo Here](http://regexr.com/3ghv9)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = "hello800 more text 1234 and 567 blah blah +33 end";
var result = str.match(/\b\d+\b/g);
console.log(result);
```

**Explanation:**

```
\b  : word boundary, make sure we don't have letter or digit before
\d+ : 1 or more digits
\b  : word boundary, make sure we don't have letter or digit after
```